# Swift - Create a UITableViewController with one static cell at the top and the rest be dynamic cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having trouble making a table view with one static cell at the very top of my table view. This table view will hold 4 buttons and the rest of the views will hold a list of the user's songs.

I have already looked into other answers on here but all of them seem to be written in Objective C not swift.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedSongs.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell", for: indexPath) as! RecentCell

        //cell.songTitle.text = albumList[indexPath.row]
        //cell.songArtist.text = artistList[indexPath.row]
        //cell.songImage.image = imageList[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
```

This is what I have been using to just set the regular table views. How would I go about modifying this code to allow for a static cell at the top and dynamic cells for the rest?​

Comment: You can’t mix static and dynamic, and you don’t need to. Just do a regular table view! If the first cell never changes, don’t change it.

Comment: @matt my problem is that the first cell stays the same but the ones after it do change. I need the entire view to be scrollable and this is the easiest way I have found to do it.

Comment: If it's the "easiest way", you would just do it and you would not be asking a question about it. But you see, it is _not_ "the easiest way", and that's why you can't do it.

Comment: @DevAlphas by static; you mean it won't scroll with content your song list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Static Cells`. Choose `Dynamic Prototypes` in your table view and create 2 prototype cells.

[image]

And return first cell in first section, other cells in second section

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else if section == 1 {
        return sortedSongs.count
    } else if section == 2 {
        return anotherArrayCount  
    }
    return 0
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell", for: indexPath) as! RecentCell
        //cell.songTitle.text = albumList[indexPath.row]
        //cell.songArtist.text = artistList[indexPath.row]
        //cell.songImage.image = imageList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use tableHeaderView in that case.

Comment: @iDevid It is another way to do this. But in which way it is better?

Comment: @iDevid I think adding it as first cell is better. If he need to change the cell button properties based on data source array count, it can be handled in cellforrow method. Like if sortedSongs is empty hide some button in first prototype cell, etc.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed for it to work.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR How would I go about expanding this system to more than just two sections?

Comment: @DevAlphas you can return any number in numberOfSections method

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I understand that but how would I extend the number of rows in section code?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I think it's better to use a tableHeaderView :)

Comment: @iDevid How it is better?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HeaderView of the table for that, just give your custom view to the . tableHeaderView property
Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let myCustomView = MyCustomView()
   tableView.tableHeaderView = myCustomView
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview